# Excel vba and XMLHTTP with ADFS - not returning xml

Tags: vba, excel, adfs, xmlhttprequest

I have an Excel macro that has been in use for years which posts to a database using an XMLHttp call. The code is digitally signed.

Recently the site which is being posted to has enabled ADFS. Now instead of getting xml back I get the contents of the ADFS authentication form. There is no prompt for credentials in it since authentication already occurred. It I open the url from a web browser it goes through as expected with existing credentials used and the page loaded.

I tried setting the trusted setting for the url and allowed external content but that didn't matter.

Have I missed something?

The html I get back looks like...

```
<html><head><title>Working...</title></head><body><form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://isvcci.jttest.com:444/"><input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" />
...
<noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form><script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script></body></html>
```

This is the vba:

```
Sub PostXml(strType As String, strAddress As String, objXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)
    Dim objHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, objXmlResponse As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strText As String
    Set objHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    objHttp.Open "POST", strAddress, False
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

    objHttp.send objXml
    Set objXmlResponse = objHttp.responseXML
    rem responseXML is always empty but responseText has the adfs page <------
    Set objNode = objXmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("root/errorMessage")
    If objNode Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error: Unable to retrieve expected response from the server." + vbCrLf + "The opportunity may not have been updated."
    Else
    ... code for success goes here
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttp wouldn't work over adfs so I used an InternetExplorer control instead. It's a hassle to get the resulting xml back though using a page which sets a form value would probably be simpler. The resulting xml gets returned formatted like what you see in a web browser. I use a simple regex to remove dashes outside of tags.

I'm not that experienced with vba and excel so there might be better ways to code this but it works.

```
Sub PostXml(strType As String, strAddress As String, objXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)
    Dim objHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, objXmlResponse As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim objDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim strText As String, strHeaders As String, strPostData As String
    Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Dim PostData() As Byte
    Dim expr As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim colMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim vbsMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    Dim sMatchString As String

    ' XMLHttp doesn't work with ADFS so browser was used

    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    strHeaders = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" & vbCrLf
    PostData = StrConv(objXml.XML, vbFromUnicode)
    MyBrowser.Visible = False
    MyBrowser.navigate strAddress, 0, "", PostData, strHeaders
    Do While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState <> 4
    Loop
    Set objDoc = MyBrowser.Document
    strText = objDoc.body.innerText
    Set expr = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    expr.Pattern = "(?:\s|&nbsp;|^)(-)(?=\s|\r|\n|$)"
    expr.IgnoreCase = True
    expr.MultiLine = True
    expr.Global = True
    strText = expr.Replace(strText, "")

    Set objXmlResponse = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set objNode = Nothing
    If objXmlResponse.LoadXML(strText) Then
       Set objNode = objXmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("root/errorMessage")
    'Else
       'MsgBox "Invalid XML " & objXmlResponse.parseError.ErrorCode & "," & objXmlResponse.parseError.reason
    End If
    MyBrowser.Quit
    Set MyBrowser = Nothing

    Rem MsgBox "response =" & vbCrLf & objXmlResponse.XML

    If objNode Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error: Unable to retrieve expected response from the server."
    Else
        strText = objNode.Text
        If strText > "" Then
            MsgBox strText, vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Else
            ' it worked, read the xml here
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```